# How to update value of an item in Class based on UISwitch action?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, indexing, uiswitch

I have item class as shown below:

```
struct Cur: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let symbol: String?
    let rank: String?
    let switchVal: Bool?
}
```

This class fills an array and array fills UITableView.

Here how I access UISwitch action:

```
@IBAction func switchBtn(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {

        // See if user is in Search Mode
        if inSearchMode {

            // if user in search mode get the Cur from filtered array
            if let switchRank = filterCur.index(where: {$0.switchVal}) {
                print("This is the rank: \(filterCur[switchRank].rank!)")

            }

        } else {
            if let switchRank = Cur.index(where: {$0.switchVal}) {
                print("This is where it is: \(Cur[switchRank])")

            }
        }

    } else {
        // Handle deleting previously selected Curs

    }
}
```

In order for me to find which item in the array is Switched On/Off I have to have the array already updated (items switchVal = true?). But, to update the array I need to know which item's switch is triggered.

So, where is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Your `UISwitch` is in a `UITableViewCell` and every `Cur` has its own cell, right?

Comment: Yes exactly setup like that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to give every `UISwitch` the index of `Cur` by assigning it to the `tag` attribute.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.switch.tag = indexPath.row
    ...
}
```

Since you now know that every switch has the index, you can get the item by accessing your array with the switch's tag.

```
@IBAction func switchBtn(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    let index = sender.tag
    let cur = Cur[index]
}
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!